# How does factoring probability distributions help?

Tags: probability, distribution

I'm trying to make sense of machine learning and am reading **Deep Learning** by Goodfellow, Bengio and Courville.  In section 3.14 they show an example of factoring a distribution then say "These factorizations can greatly reduce the number of parameters needed to describe the distribution."

What does that mean?  Equation 3.52 `p(a, b, c) = p(a)p(b|a)p(c|b)` still has all three variables on both sides.  They say something about representation "reducing the cost of representing a distribution" but what representation are they talking about?

Comment: Like they said in the book, calculating joint distributions are expensive unless you have a simple distribution (normally they aren't simple in deep learning models), so instead use directly the 3 parameters to get a sample from the distribution you factorize into distributions with less parameters like the 2 conditional probabilities and a prior probability. As an example, Gibbs sampling make use of that to simplify sampling on Deep Neural Nets.

Comment: @TiagoMartins are we calculating distributions to do deep learning?   Why do we care?  And what does "calculating distributions" mean?

Comment: You don't calculate the machine does, when you classify something the model is using a probability distribution estimated by your training to get the predicted label (higher probability). The initial weights are sampled from a distribution ... a lot of things use distributions. 
The book you're reading is not a cookbook where they teach how to use a deep learning library, they explain all math behind the deep learning models and libraries. So in the end of day, probably, you'll not care about those distributions.

Comment: I agree with Tiago, if your goal is just to "make sense of machine learning" I think you're reading the wrong book, this is quite advanced.